# why it is not necessary to use this keyword for pointer?

Tags: c++, class, oop, this

i was doing linked list and got bit confused in the class of a node

```
class node 
{
public: 
    int data;  
    node*next;  
    node(int data){
        this->data=data;
        next =NULL;
    }
}
```

so here my question is why it is not necessary to use `this` keyword for `next` pointer , I have also seen this in the class of trees where we just write `left=NULL` and `right=NULL` and not `this->left=NULL` and `this->right=NULL` why is it so ?

Comment: Your constructor definition is missing the curly braces. Add `{` after `node(int data) ` and `}` after `next =NULL;`.

Comment: The confusion here is because the name of the member data `data` is the same as the name of the argument `data`. If the names were different there would be no need for `this->` in the first line of the constructor. It's the **use** of `this->` that's the aberration, not its absence.

Answer (score 2):

That's how the language works. It has nothing to do with the variable being a pointer. An unqualified identifier inside a class will be searched in the class's scope. You'll want to use `this` when the lookup would pick up another symbol, like a parameter or local variable.

```
struct X
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    void foo(int b)
    {
         int c;

         a;       // data member X::a
         this->a; // same
         X::a;    // same

         b;       // parameter b
         this->b; // data member X::b
         X::b;    // data member X::b    

         c;       // local variable X::foo::c
         this->c; // data member X::c
         X::c;    // data member X::c    
    }
};
```